# Update the Jhipster User entity

Tags: jhipster

I use jhipster and I would like to modify the User entity and add fields and relationships.

I use jhipster entity user and this command is not good.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

User is not a JHipster entity, the generator does not manage it. You must edit the code manually or add a related entity where you put additional fields, see doc: https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/022_tip_registering_user_with_additional_information.html

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a problem where you need to alter the User entity, Its recommend not doing that. Modifying this default entity might break your app depending on the nature of the changes.

Instead, there are other available solutions like:

- creating an entity composed of the User entity
- extending the User entity

**Using composition**
by using OneToOne relation like this

```
entity ApplicationUser {
  additionalField Integer min(42) max(42)
}

relationship OneToOne {
  ApplicationUser{internalUser} to User
}
```

Or

**Using inheritance**
This solution does the same thing as the previous one, but isn’t as straightforward as the first one because you need to:

create a new entity by hand,
adapt the code to make it use this new entity,
potentially manage yourself the database migration to persist this new entity (depending on the nature of the changes).

More info: https://www.jhipster.tech/user-entity/